# Adding 4TB local SR to XenServer 5.6 SP2

Tags: storage, lvm, xenserver

I'm trying to add a secondary local SR to XenServer but not having any success. The server has two RAID 10 arrays; the primary array was selected for VM storage in XenServer setup - it totals 272GB. The secondary array is 4TB in total but there's no option to add it to XenServer.

I tried using FDISK but it complained it was larger than 2.2TB and suggested using parted. So I used parted and followed http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/fdisk-unable-to-create-partition-greater-2tb.html but when I try using mkfs.ext3, it says:

```
[root@l1ps01xen ~]# mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
mke2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
mkfs.ext3: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
        partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
        a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
        to re-read your partition table.

[root@l1ps01xen ~]#
```

I'm not booting to the 4TB SR, just using it to store VMs.

I would really appreciate any assistance in getting this SR added to XenServer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the drive formatted to 4TB in the end by running through the tutorial again, but this time for the mkpart bit I specified "0 4000GB" instead of "0 0". Both Linux and XenServer have accepted the new 4TB drive now.